# ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c bash ./docker_build.sh" did not complete successfully: exit code: 2

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, build, dockerfile

I'm new to docker. I've a DockerFile.
I'm trying to build a docker image from it.
But I'm getting the following error:

```
pegasus@pegasus:~/Documents/x86-sok-master/gt$ ls ./
aarch64  arm32  binutils  gcc  llvm  mips  proto  requirements.txt  test  x86
pegasus@pegasus:~/Documents/x86-sok-master/gt$ ls ./x86/
build  build.sh  clang32.rc  clang64.rc  docker_build.sh  Dockerfile  gcc32.rc  gcc64.rc  requirements.txt
```

```
Dockerfile:29
--------------------
  27 |     COPY ./ /gt_x86
  28 |     WORKDIR /gt_x86/x86
  29 | >>> RUN bash ./docker_build.sh
  30 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c bash ./docker_build.sh" did not complete successfully: exit code: 2
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: What is in ./x86/docker_build.sh?

Comment: It was a script to build Clang.

Comment: Sounds like you will have to debug that script. First thing I would try is to remove the `bash` from that `RUN` command; it's quite possible your image does not have `bash`.

Comment: I have the same error on linux, although i tried to run my script on windows and it ran successfully. Did you manage to solve the issue?